# Is there a one line kubectl command to add the nodeSelector in the pod yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, nodeselector

I was wondering if there was a one line kubectl command to add the nodeSelector in the pod yaml? (I have already attached a label to the node) I am trying to automate this and hence I want to avoid manually downloading the yaml file and adding the nodeSelector. Any ideas using sed or kubectl replace would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `nodeSelector` in pod spec.

As the k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) : nodeSelector is the simplest recommended form of node selection constraint. nodeSelector is a field of PodSpec. It specifies a map of key-value pairs. For the pod to be eligible to run on a node, the node must have each of the indicated key-value pairs as labels (it can have additional labels as well). The most common usage is one key-value pair.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

## update

I found a way to do this:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 -ti --rm test --image=ubuntu:20.04 --overrides='{"spec": { "nodeSelector": {"nodename": "test-node"}}}'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, normally I download the file and add the nodeSelector manually to the pod spec. I am trying to automate this via a 1 liner if there is a way?

Comment: Do you have an example of adding and applying the nodeSelector using kubectl edit to the pod spec? Appreciate your help!

Comment: I got a command for doing this, try this one

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot!

Comment: @Contraboy I'd reckon that your comment about `$ kubectl patch` could be posted as answer as it's also a valid solution. Please post your comment as an answer with some explanation to give it more visibility for future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ended up using this command kubectl patch deployments DEPLOYMENTNAME -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"nodeSelector": {"YOURLABEL": "YOURVALUE"}}}}}